# Removing\Popping vertex without removing edges

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, reference-request, terminology

So, I came with a short inductive\algorithmic proof for the following theorem :

> Let $G$ be a simple connected graph.
> Then $G$ can be decomposed into paths of length $2$ iff it has an even number of edges.

In my proof, I used the notion of removing a vertex $v$ with adjacent edges $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_d$ and replacing it with vertices $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_d$ where each $v_i$ has degree $1$ and is adjacent only to $e_i$.

Which looks something like this :

[image]

My question here is that is there any already built terminology\notation for this? (I've found vertex splitting but that's not what I want)